# Conv2D: How can I get the values of each filter

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

My model:

```
classifier = Sequential()

# Convolutional + MaxPooling -> 1
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)))
convout1 = Activation('relu')
classifier.add(convout1)
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

I am running the following code to get weights

```
classifier.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
```

It returns an array of `3x3x3x32`. Shouldn't it return 32 matrices of `3x3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights shape is correct, because the convolutional filter is applied to the *whole 3D input volume* and the parameters for different channels are *not shared* (though they are shared spatially). See the picture from [CS231n class](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv):

[image: convolution]

Yes, the *output volume* is obtained by summing up the convolutions across the depth volume, but the parameters in each channel are different.

In your case, the channels are *RGB* (since `input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)`), the spatial filter size is `3x3` and there are `32` filters. Hence the result shape is `3x3x3x32` and shape of each filter is `3x3x3`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the return value has the right shape. What you are not considering is that each of the 32 filters is 3x3 in spatial dimensions, and has three channels, same as the input. This means that each filter also works on the channels dimension. What you expect would only be valid in the case of doing 2D convolution on a one channel image.